# c:\ınetpub\wwwroot\mysite\website\sitecore\shell\override is invalid

Tags: sitecore

I install sitecore 6.4 but after login i take this error

The directory name c:\ınetpub\wwwroot\mysite\website\sitecore\shell\override is invalid. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

I uninstall sitecore and install again but result same. Someone can help me pls.

Comment: The "i" in your "inetpub" has no dot -- I bet that's related.

Comment: I know, i chacked folder name, its normal. i took same error before for icons.config  and i change to ı, it solved, but i couldn`t change inetpub to ınetpub because it says "The action can`t be complated because the folder or a file in it is open in another program.". I closed iis but result same.

Comment: Have you tried installing to a different location? out of the inetpub folder, just for test... And what is the version of your OS? Is it non-English?

Comment: I tried with different location its work until create new template, i took script error so i couldn`t create new template. I am using win7 and its english.

Comment: I found solution. My OS is english but i choose turkey for location so in administrative ==> welcome screen and new user accounts ==> input language,format and location was turkey i changed it to united states it solved.

Comment: If it's resolved, add the answer explaining it, so that other know where to look without scrolling the comments.

Answer (score 11):

By default this folder is not created when you create a fresh install of Sitecore. Have had this many times, and essentially you must manually create the folder, and also ensure the app pool identity has write permissions to this folder. If you have your Visual Studio solution open, also close and reopen as the change will not be picked up if you are running webdev.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. My problem was i had my project committed on Git and I was trying to pull files from GIT to my local to setup the project.

The problem with GIT is that it doesnt commit empty folders so \website\sitecore\shell\override was not committed to the repo, and when i pulled, the folder didnt existed on my local as well.

Creating the folder manually resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to include this folder in your project, that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @pranav-shah, git doesn't support adding empty folders so if you are using git and you are doing clean builds it is likely you are running into this problem.

To get around it you can just create an empty file in the override folder. I recommend following the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422128/202) answer and call it `.keep`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into this, it's the app pool identity missing write permissions to the folder. Often applies to following folders too, under the sitecore directory:
* shell\controls\debug
* shell\applications\debug

(I think there's one more but too tired to remember right now).

If you run the installer it normally takes care of these issues. Also be sure to read the manual installation steps in the Sitecore documentation, available on the Sitecore Developer Network.